# Vagrant box after rebooting itself doesn't mount synced folders

Tags: vagrant

When I reboot vagrant box from inside it with `sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now` synced folders remain empty.

How can I manage remounting synced folders?

Comment: It is absolutely necessary to reboot the virtual machine from inside?

Comment: Yes, the service running inside the box needs to restart the OS after a number of requests were served.

Answer (score 2):

you should run `vagrant reload` from the host; if you reboot from the VM sync folder will not be remount as it needs to be done from the host

If the reboot is done automatically and after its done you will need to issue the mount command yourself

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf <name of shared> <path>
```

for example

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf vagrant /vagrant/
```

Comment: I know that `vagrant reload` mounts synced folders, but I need them to be mounted when VM reboots itself

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, re-mount the volumes, e.g.:

```sh
sudo mount -a
```